# How to merge two files in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Lets say that in an excel sheet

first column has

> a
>   s
>   d
>   f
>   h
>   j

and second column has

> s
>   d
>   f

If the contents in column2 match with the contents in column1 then it should be replaced with null.

The final results would be as shown below, since s,d and f are common across the two files.

> a
>   null
>   null
>   null
>   h
>   j

How do I achieve this in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a basic formula

*Edit: I used two columns from the same sheet in the same workbook. If you actually have two files then column B should be linked directly in from the second workbook*

- In C1 put `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"null")` and copy down
- Copy and Paste Special Value Column C back over Column A if you want to replace the values

[image]

Comment: Thank you - it was nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "files", but you can probably do this with the MATCH function if it's just a one time process. Otherwise you'll need a bit of VBA as well.

Comment: It's a one time process. Can you please provide the code using the MATCH function or VBA? It need not be seperate files, can be two columns in an excel sheet.

Comment: Jeremy, *'probably do this with the MATCH'* this is more a comment than an answer.